# Combine pandas dataframe columns into 1 column and ignore NaN

Tags: python, pandas

In python 3.7 and pandas 1.3.0

If there is a dataframe df with columns a,b,c

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
[
{'a':'1'},
{'b':''},
{'c':'3'}
])
```

Trying to combine the column a, b, c into a new column abc using

```
    df['abc'] = df.a.astype(str) + ' ' + df.b.astype(
        str) +  ' ' + df.c.astype(str)
```

This will make the columns like

```
>>> df['abc']
0    1 nan nan
1     nan  nan
2    nan nan 3
```

Is there anyway  I can combine these 3 columns into one, while don't return any value if the column is empty? Something like this:

```
>>> df['abc']
0    1
1    
2    3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BENY's answer is great if you only have 1 non-`nan` value per row like your sample `df`.

However, if you have multiple non-`nan` per row, e.g.:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1',np.nan,np.nan], 'b': ['2',np.nan,np.nan], 'c': [np.nan,np.nan,'3']})

#      a    b    c
# 0    1    2  NaN
# 1  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2  NaN  NaN    3
```

Then use [`fillna('')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) as a more general solution.

- Either `fillna('')` before concatenating:

  ```py
  df = df.fillna('').astype(str)
  (df.a + ' ' + df.b + ' ' + df.c).str.strip()
  ```
- Or `fillna('')` before applying `join`:

  ```py
  df.fillna('').astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1).str.strip()
  ```
- Or `fillna('')` before taking the `sum`:

  ```py
  df.fillna('').astype(str).add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.strip()
  ```

Output:

```
0    1 2
1       
2      3
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with `ffill`

```
s = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
Out[59]: 
0    1
1     
2    3
Name: c, dtype: object
```